# Excel VBA Select Cells based on Conditional Formatting applied

Tags: vba, excel

I am watching lots of videos explaining the code for selecting cells but I cannot figure out how to accomplish the following. Anyone able to provide assistance?

To select all the cells in Column A that have conditional formatting applied to them. There will be cells that are colored red and also cells that are not. They will be sorted by cell color with the red at the top. I only want to copy the red "rows" over to a new worksheet.

I need to copy the entire row(s) each time but the number of conditionally formatted rows will change from worksheet to worksheet so I need some kind of loop I think that will stop at the first row that is not red.

Peace and respect,

Comment: Why not search for rows that match the condition of the conditional formatting instead of searching for the result of the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

this is an interesting problem with no easy solution, just workarounds.

What I found the easiest is the method by steffan z I found on Microsoft forums (link [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/331a74a2-8f24-4a8a-8a23-5d3b99fcbab6/excel-2007-evaluate-formatcondition?forum=isvvba))

He suggested using Autofilter and filtering by color to show only the color you are looking for.

Example:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A11")

rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

It's not perfect and you'll probably need to turn off screen updating to prevent flickering, but it should do the trick.

Marek

Comment: AFAIK, AutoFilter's *filter by color* does not work on interior or font color assigned by a Conditional Formatting Rule.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, it does, the code in the answer is mine, I tested it myself to be sure

Comment: You're right of course. I don't know where I got that mistaken impression.